# How to setState the object of the object of state

Tags: reactjs, react-native

**Goal**: I have two square and I want to change selected square's location. While I'm doing it, I need to change selected square's x-coordinate, y-coordinate, width, and height.

Here is my state which holds the data for square information.

```
state = {
    gestureState: {},
    thumbSize: 100,
    left: width(100) / 2,
    top: height(100) / 2,
    taggedClothes: {
      0: {id:0, left:100, top:100, thumbSize:100}, <- I want to setState this
      1: {id:1, left:200, top:200, thumbSize:200},
    },
    selectedClothId : 0,
  }
```

**Problem:** `taggedClothes` have two square information and I want to change only selected problem but I'm getting compile error

Here I'm performing setState its taggedClothes[0]

```
// this.state.selectedColorId = 0
var deep = _.cloneDeep(this.state.taggedClothes[this.state.selectedColorId]);
          deep.left = left
          deep.top = top
          deep.thumbSize = thumbSize
          this.setState({
            gestureState: {
              ...gestureState
            },
            taggedClothes[0]: deep  <- Getting Compile Error 
          })
```

If your have any other suggestion, Please suggest other option!

Comment: A good question to work on :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key `taggedClothes[0]` is not valid.  You need to spread the `taggedClothes` and only replace the one that changed:

```
  var deep = _.cloneDeep(this.state.taggedClothes[this.state.selectedColorId]);
  deep.left = left
  deep.top = top
  deep.thumbSize = thumbSize
  this.setState({
    gestureState: {
      ...gestureState
    },
    taggedClothes: {
      ...taggedClothes,
      [this.state.selectedColorId]: deep
    }
  })
```

Comment: Continue from this problem, this may be easy for you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47309489/touchablewithoutfeedback-onpress-doesnt-work

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access your taggedClothes object like an array. 
change this:

```
 taggedClothes: { 
      0: {id:0, left:100, top:100, thumbSize:100}, <- I want to setState this
      1: {id:1, left:200, top:200, thumbSize:200},
 },
```

to that:

```
 taggedClothes: [ 
      {id:0, left:100, top:100, thumbSize:100}, 
      {id:1, left:200, top:200, thumbSize:200},
 ],
```

now you should be able to access taggedClothes.